# Using placeholder in StringBuilder

Tags: c#

I have something like this:

```
int processed = 123;
//
....
builder.Append("Export: Processed {0} Teacher(s)", processed.ToString());
```

But it doesn't compile and says `"String is not assignable to char."`

What is wrong?

Comment: try builder.AppendFormat("Export: Processed {0} Teacher(s)", processed.ToString());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cazfhf32.aspx); also, calling `ToString` on the `processed` is not necessary:

```
builder.AppendFormat("Export: Processed {0} Teacher(s)", processed);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pass in a format string to your `StringBuilder` you have to call the `AppendFormat` overload passing in your format string. Also the `.ToString()` call is unnecessary since `AppendFormat` will implicitly call `.ToString()` on each parameter. Therefore your solution can be written as follows:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int processed = 123;
builder.AppendFormat("Export: Processed {0} Teacher(s)", processed);
```

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat.aspx)

> Appends the string returned by processing a composite format string, which contains zero or more format items, to this instance. Each format item is replaced by the string representation of a corresponding object argument.
>   This member is overloaded. For complete information about this member, including syntax, usage, and examples, click a name in the overload list.

Answer (score 4):

There is no overload for `StringBuilder.Append(string, string)`

Use `StringBuilder.AppendFormat(string, object)` instead.

Comment: No such method exist

Answer (score 2):

Use string.Format

```
 builder.Append(string.Format("Export: Processed {0} Teacher(s)", processed));
```

Comment: A nice and generic solution, although `builder.AppendFormat` is a more obvious choice in this case. But String.Format will also work in cases, where there is not special *Format version of a method.